# Cannot upload P12 certificate to Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I have created many certificates in my day and have never had an issue.  But today when trying to upload a certificate to Firebase, I get this message:

```
There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again
```

Yesterday there was an issue uploading certs, but they said it's been corrected.  However, I'm still having the issue.

Does anyone know of any tricks or solutions that are not documented that may work?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related (because of the date conflict), but it seems like a known issue. See [here](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Console/16023).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're uploading the "certificate" part and not the "private" part. Apparently there is (at least was - check out [Firebase: Cannot upload production APNs certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786677/firebase-cannot-upload-production-apns-certificate)) a documentation bug in this area.

Answer (score 0):

You should export only the certificate and don't select the private key . Please see this screenshot

[image]