# error occurred while updating your APNS Certificate IOS Notification Firebase

Tags: ios, notifications, ionic2, certificate, firebase-cloud-messaging

My error when upload APNS Certificate Develop IOS

How to fix it ?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possibilities-
1. When export p12 from keychain, don't export on private key, right click on parent node of private key, see the screenshot [image]

2. There are two kind of p12 certifications, including Development and Production certification, make sure you are uploading the correct one.

Comment: FYI-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786677/firebase-cannot-upload-production-apns-certificate

Answer (score 0):

In my case, **I had to remove the passphrase** (which OpenSSL was reading fine but not Google), and then it worked.

To [remove the passphrase](https://serverfault.com/a/633820/381264):

```sh
openssl pkcs12 -in apns-certificate.p12 -nodes -out temp.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -in temp.pem  -out unprotected.p12
rm temp.pem
```