# Getting error incorrect password on google console in firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created .p12 developer(No password) push cert by exporting Apple development ios push certificate (selected private key also).

I am using firebase push notification, while uploading .p12 file on [Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com) its showing [image: incorrect password],

I have also created another .p12 with password but getting same error on Google console, Why so?

As of this  [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786677/firebase-cannot-upload-production-apns-certificate) which uses only certificate part of .p12-Yes it uploaded successfully but i am not getting push notification from this method.
Anyone faced the same?

Comment: Did you try exporting certificates from Keychain and Uploading it to Firebase?

Comment: @SatishBabariya Yes